# Session storage option

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to learning session storage. At the moment session storage works except for state for my session storage does not work. The state doesn't get displayed once I go to another page or refresh the page, it will go blank like when you are filling in the form for the first time again. Html for state is as shown below. How do I properly code this for a session storage? I also do not want to have any JavaScript library in my code so a solution without it is mch appreciated.

```
        <p><label for="state">*State:</label> 
        <select name="state" id="state" required="required">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>         
        <option value="state">VIC</option>
        <option value="state">NSW</option>
        <option value="state">QLD</option>
        <option value="state">NT</option>
        <option value="state">WA</option>
        <option value="state">SA</option>
        <option value="state">TAS</option>
        <option value="state">ACT</option>
        </select></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
"use strict";
/*get variables from form and check rules*/  
function validate(){
    var errMsg = "";                /* stores the error message */
    var result = true;              /* assumes no errors */
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var familyName = document.getElementById("familyName").value;
    var midName = document.getElementById("midName").value;
    var male = document.getElementById("male").checked;
    var female = document.getElementById("female").checked;
    var street = document.getElementById("street").value;
    var suburb = document.getElementById("suburb").value;
    var state = document.getElementById("state").options[document.getElementById("state").selectedIndex].text;
    var postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
    var XML = document.getElementById("XML").checked;
    var Java = document.getElementById("Java").checked;
    var Python = document.getElementById("Python").checked;
    var SQL = document.getElementById("SQL").checked;
    var PERL = document.getElementById("PERL").checked;
    var MySQL = document.getElementById("MySQL").checked;
    var Windows = document.getElementById("Windows").checked;
    var UNIX = document.getElementById("UNIX").checked;
    var Linux = document.getElementById("Linux").checked;
    var other = document.getElementById("other").checked;
    var otherText = document.getElementById("otherText").value;
    var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value.split("/");
    var date = new Date(dob[2], parseInt(dob[1]) - 1, dob[0]);
    var today = new Date();
    var age = today.getFullYear() - date.getFullYear(); 

    //get varibles from form and check rules here
    // if something is wrong set result = false, and concatenate error message
    //Validation for Date of birth
    if (age >= 80){  // Checks if age is over 80
        errMsg = errMsg + "You must be 80 or younger to apply for this job\n";
        result = false;
    }

    if (age <= 15){  // Checks if age is under 15
        errMsg = errMsg + "You must be 15 or older to apply for this job\n";    
        result = false;
    }

    //Validation for state and corresponding postcode
    if (!(postcode.charAt(0) == 3 || postcode.charAt(0) == 8) && state == "VIC") {
        errMsg = errMsg + "Your state and postcode do not match. State VIC postcodes must start with a 3 or 8\n";
        result = false;
    } else if (!(postcode.charAt(0) == 1 || postcode.charAt(0) == 2) && state == "NSW") {
        errMsg = errMsg + "Your state and postcode do not match. State NSW postcodes must start with a 1 or 2\n";
        result = false;
    } else if (!(postcode.charAt(0) == 4 || postcode.charAt(0) == 9) && state == "QLD") {
        errMsg = errMsg + "Your state and postcode do not match. State QLD postcodes must start with a 4 or 9\n";
        result = false;
    } else if (!(postcode.charAt(0) == 0) && state == "NT") {
        errMsg = errMsg + "Your state and postcode do not match. State NT postcodes must start with a 0\n";
        result = false;
    } else if (!(postcode.charAt(0) == 6) && state == "WA") {
        errMsg = errMsg + "Your state and postcode do not match. State WA postcodes must start with a 6\n";
        result = false;
    } else if (!(postcode.charAt(0) == 5) && state == "SA") {
        errMsg = errMsg + "Your state and postcode do not match. State SA postcodes must start with a 5\n";
        result = false;
    } else if (!(postcode.charAt(0) == 7) && state == "TAS") {
        errMsg = errMsg + "Your state and postcode do not match. State TAS postcodes must start with a 7\n";
        result = false;
    } else if (!(postcode.charAt(0) == 0) && state == "ACT") {
        errMsg = errMsg + "Your state and postcode do not match. State ACT postcodes must start with a 0\n";
        result = false;
    } else {
        result = true;
    }

    //Validation of other skill so checks if other skill box is checked and if so will check textbox for text
    if (other && document.getElementById("otherText").value.trim().length===0) {
        errMsg = errMsg + "You have selected other skills, you must enter one other skill in the text box\n";
        result = false;
    }

    if (errMsg != "") { //only display message box if there is something to show
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = errMsg;
    }

    if (result == true) {
        storeForm(firstName, familyName, midName, dob, male, female, street, suburb, state, postcode, email, number, XML, Java, Python, SQL, PERL, MySQL, Windows, UNIX, Linux, other, otherText)
    }
    return result;    //if false the information will not be sent to the server
}



function storeForm(firstName, familyName, midName, dob, male, female, street, suburb, state, postcode, email, number, XML, Java, Python, SQL, PERL, MySQL, Windows, UNIX, Linux, other, otherText) {
//get values and assign them to sessionStorage attribute
//used the same name for the attrubute and the element id to avoid confustion
sessionStorage.firstName = firstName;
sessionStorage.familyName = familyName;
sessionStorage.midName = midName;
sessionStorage.dob = dob;
sessionStorage.male = male;
sessionStorage.female = female;
sessionStorage.street = street;
sessionStorage.suburb = suburb;
sessionStorage.state = state;
sessionStorage.postcode = postcode;
sessionStorage.email = email;
sessionStorage.number = number;
sessionStorage.XML = XML;
sessionStorage.Java = Java;
sessionStorage.Python = Python;
sessionStorage.SQL = SQL;
sessionStorage.PERL = PERL;
sessionStorage.MySQL = MySQL;   
sessionStorage.Windows = Windows;
sessionStorage.UNIX = UNIX;
sessionStorage.Linux = Linux;
sessionStorage.other = other;
sessionStorage.otherText = otherText;
}

//check if session day on user exists and if so prefill the form
function prefillForm() {
if (sessionStorage.firstName != undefined) {
    document.getElementById("firstName").value = sessionStorage.firstName;
    document.getElementById("familyName").value = sessionStorage.familyName;
    document.getElementById("midName").value = sessionStorage.midName;
    document.getElementById("dob").value = sessionStorage.dob;
    if (sessionStorage.male == ("true")) {
        document.getElementById("male").checked = true;
    }
    if (sessionStorage.female == ("true")) {
        document.getElementById("female").checked = true;
    }
    document.getElementById("street").value = sessionStorage.street;
    document.getElementById("suburb").value = sessionStorage.suburb;
    document.getElementById("state").value = sessionStorage.state;
    document.getElementById("postcode").value = sessionStorage.postcode;
    document.getElementById("email").value = sessionStorage.email;
    document.getElementById("number").value = sessionStorage.number;
    if (sessionStorage.XML == ("true")) {
        document.getElementById("XML").checked = true;
    }
    if (sessionStorage.Java == ("true")) {
        document.getElementById("Java").checked = true;
    }       
    if (sessionStorage.Python == ("true")) {
        document.getElementById("Python").checked = true;
    }
    if (sessionStorage.SQL == ("true")) {
        document.getElementById("SQL").checked = true;
    }
    if (sessionStorage.PERL == ("true")) {
        document.getElementById("PERL").checked = true;
    }
    if (sessionStorage.MySQL == ("true")) {
        document.getElementById("MySQL").checked = true;
    }
    if (sessionStorage.Windows == ("true")) {
        document.getElementById("Windows").checked = true;
    }
    if (sessionStorage.UNIX == ("true")) {
        document.getElementById("UNIX").checked = true;
    }
    if (sessionStorage.Linux == ("true")) {
        document.getElementById("Linux").checked = true;
    }
    if (sessionStorage.other == ("true")) {
        document.getElementById("other").checked = sessionStorage.other;
    }
    document.getElementById("otherText").value = sessionStorage.otherText;  
}
}
```

Comment: _"state for my session storage does not work."_ you need to explain how it is not working. Are you getting the wrong value? If so what should the value have been compared to what you got?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add it. The state doesn't get saved like the rest. State is the only one that goes back to being blank where as the rest still has the information

Comment: Try using ```sessionStorage.getItem("state");``` and ```sessionStorage.setItem("state", state);```

Comment: @HeinrichHenning nope didn't work, got any other ideas on how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by it goes back to being black? That `sessionStorage.state` goes to being a empty string, ie `""`, `undefined`, `null` Or that the select element goes black? Did you check your `state` value through the various methods, ie `console.log(state)` in your `validate()` function, and in `storeForm()`. Did you check `console.log(sessionStorage.state)` in the `prefillForm()` function? Did any of those log a value you werent expecting